# Prove that a set is bounded above by a particular value

Tags: real-analysis

Let $e=sup\{(1+ \frac 1n)^n\}$. Prove that the set $\{(1+ \frac 2n)^n\}$ is bounded above by $e^2$.
I don't really know how to go about this question, I thought that I could start by finding a value for e, but that didn't work, as taking the limit as *n* approaches infinity gives e to be 1, when in reality if you substitute in very large *n*, it is something around 2.72. How should I tackle this? I'm totally stuck.
Thanks in advance for your replies :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

If we assume $$e=\sup \left\{\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n|n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$$ having in mind that when $n=2m$ it is $$\left(1+\frac{2}{2m}\right)^{2m}=\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^m\right)^2\le e^2.$$

Comment: Thank you, this helps so much

Comment: One minor point, this assumes that $(1+(2/n))^n$ is increasing as $n$ increases. Apart from that +1

Answer (score 0):

*Less elegant than @mfl's answer.*

Consider the most general case of
$$A_n=\left(1+\frac kn\right)^n\implies \log(A_n)=n \log\left(1+\frac kn\right)$$ Now, use the fact that, by Taylor expansion,
$$\log (1+\epsilon)=\epsilon -\frac{\epsilon ^2}{2}+\frac{\epsilon ^3}{3}+O\left(\epsilon ^4\right)$$
Make $\epsilon=\frac kn$ to get
$$\log(A_n)=n\left( \frac{k}{n}-\frac{k^2}{2 n^2}+\frac{k^3}{3
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)=k-\frac{k^2}{2 n}+\frac{k^3}{3 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Reusing Taylor
$$A_n=e^{\log(A_n)}=e^k-\frac{e^k k^2}{2 n}+\frac{e^k k^3 (3 k+8)}{24
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$A_n=e^k \left(1-\frac{k^2}{2 n}+\frac{k^3 (3 k+8)}{24
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \right)$$